# Trigger subquery returns more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm having a problem in this SQL Server trigger, I want to update info on `Devices` table after each insert on `Mindframe` table but  when I have 2 entries separated by milliseconds, it gives an error saying it's returning more than 1 value.

Can someone explain me why ? Or point out my mistake ...

Trigger

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER device_update 
ON MindFrame
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        RETURN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @dev NVARCHAR(6)
        DECLARE @lat NVARCHAR(45)
        DECLARE @lng NVARCHAR(45)
        DECLARE @bat FLOAT

        SET @dev = (SELECT  device from inserted)
        SET @lat = (SELECT latitude from inserted)
        SET @lng = (SELECT longitude from inserted)
        SET @bat = (SELECT battery from inserted)

        UPDATE Devices
        SET lat = @lat, lng = @lng, bat = @bat, last_seen = GETDATE()
        WHERE @dev = Devices.device
    END
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `inserted` wrong.  It can contain multiple rows.  It needs to be treated like a *table* (or technically a view).  Never assume `inserted` or `deleted` has only one row.

The trigger is even easier to write this way:

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE d
        SET lat = i.latitude, 
            lng = i.longitude, 
            bat = i.battery,
            last_seen = GETDATE()
        FROM inserted i JOIN
             devices d
             on i.device = d.device
END;
```

You don't need to check if `inserted` has rows (if there are none, nothing gets updated).  You don't need to define local variables.  The code is shorter . . . and it works.

Comment: Thank you very much !!! Now I get it, I see that I have still to learn more quirks about sql.